# jQuery .load(): loading a div when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, load, click

I would like to achieve that when clicking in an image, in the div where this image is, a div with other content from another .html is loaded, but I can't get it done.

If I do, the following, it works perfectly:

```
$('#windows_link').click(function(){
        $('#apps_container').html("Hi!");
    });
```

But if I do the following, it does not work; it doesn't do anything actually:

```
$('#windows_link').click(function(){
        $('#apps_container').load('windows_apps.html #apps_container');
    });
```

Any help, please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you used a tool like Firebug to determine if your 'windows_apps.html #apps_container' is actually returning anything?

Comment: Are you trying this locally? if so, in which browser?

Comment: Hi! @Gregg I haven't yet used it, but that should exist!

Comment: @Nick Craver I am trying locally in Chrome

Comment: Can you remove the `#apps_container` after windows_apps.html please & check if it loads anything into the original `#apps_container`

Comment: @Bit Destroyer: jQuery's `.load()` specifically allows you to add selectors to extract a specific part of the downloaded page, unlike `.get()`. See `Loading Page Fragments` here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @noloman - that's a cross-domain request in chrome, and won't work...that's where you're getting blocked.  If you try it on an actual site (or local webserver) you should be good.

Comment: @Nick - how could the url `windows_apps.html` result in a cross-domain request?

Comment: @Acorn - he's trying it *locally*, any other path is another domain when you're local, in some browsers...and in chrome this is true.

Comment: if I delete #apps_container it doesn't work either

Comment: @noloman - the problem isn't the selector, it's the load itself being blocked as I said above, look at the network panel in chrome to see what I mean.

Comment: ok, it works in Firefox!

Comment: @noloman so this will work on chrome when you publish the code online.

Comment: Network panel says: XMLHttpRequest cannot load windows_apps.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're local any other HTML path is treated as *another* domain in certain browsers (Chrome is on the list).  That means any AJAX request (what [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) does underneath) you attempt will be blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

What you have will likely work fine...just not locally, in Chrome.

You can verify this by testing in another browser like Firefox, or by launching chrome [with a command line switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) to disable this safety feature (*only* for testing!, turn it off after):

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Comment: Wonderful, so I will just try in another browser and trust that it'll work when uploaded to a web server. Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: @noloman: Really, unless you have a good reason not too, it is better to test develop on a server that has the same environment as the site will eventually be hosted on.  Preferably that server.  Otherwise there may well be unforeseen differences, like this.

Comment: @noloman - I'm with orbling here, setup a localhost web server (lots of free options there) to do your testing and you'll be much happier (and less pushing to another site to test the small stuff).

Answer (score 0):

If the first try works correctly, i assume the problem is here

```
.load('windows_apps.html #apps_container');
```

When you click the link, do you see a call in your .net panel of firebug or of your debugging console(does the ajax call complete succesfully)?

Is windows_apps.html in the same folder of the page script that calls it?

is there a div called apps_container into that page?